# Remove tag with Jquery

Tags: html, jquery

I have two tags. I just want to remove the second one with Jquery, not sure how to do that.

```html
<canvas id="compoundingChart" height="480" width="1204" style="display: block; height: 240px; width: 602px;" class="chartjs-render-monitor"></canvas>

<canvas id="compoundingChart" height="120"></canvas>
```

I have however seen this code

```js
$(function() {
    $("#segement1,#segement2,#segement3").hide()
});
```

But tried doing this and it didnt work

```js
$(function() {
    $("<canvas id="compoundingChart" height="120"></canvas>").hide()
});
```

Comment: Two of the same ID in the page is an error; you won't reliably be able to target them by ID as `#compoundingChart`. You *may* be able to through its location in the DOM (e.g.`$('div.someParentElementOfTheBadOne canvas')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is a syntax error.  This error is surely being reported on your browser's development console.  Always check there first.

Even after correcting the syntax... This *creates* an element, sets it to be hidden, and then does nothing with it (not even add it to the page):

```
$('<canvas id="compoundingChart" height="120"></canvas>').hide()
```

Contrast that with the code you've "seen", which *selects* elements by their `id` and hides them:

```
$("#segement1,#segement2,#segement3").hide()
```

If you're going to use jQuery to select elements, you'd do well to familiarize yourself with [jQuery selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) (most of which is essentially identical to CSS selectors).

You can select your element by its `id`, but first you need to correct your HTML to not re-use `id` values.  For example:

```
<canvas id="compoundingChart" height="480" width="1204" style="display: block; height: 240px; width: 602px;" class="chartjs-render-monitor"></canvas>

<canvas id="compoundingChart2" height="120"></canvas>
```

Now that `id` values are distinct, you can use your jQuery selector to target the `id` of the element you want:

```
$("#compoundingChart2").hide()
```

---

**Edit:** If you can't modify the HTML then you can also use this:

```
$('canvas[height="120"]').hide();
```

There are many, many ways to select elements in the document, you are encouraged to research and learn more.  In this case you'd be selecting by the tag name (`canvas`) and a specific attribute value (`height="120"`).

Note also of course that if you can't correct the HTML then you still have *invalid HTML*, so any behavior of the HTML/CSS/JS is potentially undefined and browser-specific.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. 

Unfortunately I dont have access to the html so its showing up like this 

<canvas id="compoundingChart" height="480" width="1204" style="display: block; height: 240px; width: 602px;" class="chartjs-render-monitor"></canvas>

<canvas id="compoundingChart" height="120"></canvas>

That's why I just want to be able to remove the second set of code.

Comment: @JessicaRoberts: I've updated the answer with another option.  Though keep in mind that you have invalid HTML, so any given behavior could be undefined.

Comment: Hi David were you able to look at the page I sent you above?

Comment: @JessicaRoberts: I had no reason to.  What are you asking?  If there's a new problem to be solved then that should be addressed in a new question, not in comments on an existing question.

Comment: Its the same problem unfortunately. Your code didnt work for me and I thought showing you the url you'll see my issue.

Comment: @JessicaRoberts: A few things... (1) If the question hasn't been answered then marking it as having been answered was misleading. (2) If something "didn't work", please elaborate on that in an update on the question. Because the code shown here [demonstrably works](https://jsfiddle.net/w12rt3jk/) (the elements have no content, but the styling can be observed in your browser's debugging tools). (3) Relevant code about the problem needs to be in the question itself as a [mcve], not linked off-site. (4) Visiting that link now shows a "Page not found" result.

Comment: oops sorry! I have made the page live now. Sorry I marked it as being helpful, didnt think it was going to mark it as completed. My bad.

Comment: @JessicaRoberts: If I load that page and execute `$('canvas[height="120"]').hide();` in the browser console, that "empty block" is indeed hidden.  Observing in the browser's debugging tools, the element in question becomes `<canvas id="compoundingChart" height="120" style="display: none;"></canvas>` as expected.  What exactly is the problem?  Please update the question to elaborate on the problem, don't just paste off-site links in comments and say "it didn't work".

Comment: Gotcha thank you